# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| \le 1 + 2|z|^{10/3}$ for all $z$. Prove that $f$ is a cubic polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show that an entire function bounded by |z|^{10/3} is cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213491/show-that-an-entire-function-bounded-by-z10-3-is-cubic)

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| \le 1 + 2|z|^{10/3}$ for all $z$. Prove that $f$ is a cubic polynomial.

I thought about using the Extended Liouville Theorem:

If f is entire and for some integer $k \ge 0$ there exists positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that $|f(z)| \le A + B|z|^k$ for all $z$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$.

I found a similar problem here, which helped me a lot: [if $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \leq 1+|z|^{1/2}$, why must $f$ be constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151700/if-f-is-entire-and-fz-leq-1z1-2-why-must-f-be-constant)

I replicated the approach to obtain an upper bound. Here's what I got:

Since $f$ is entire, it can be expressed as a power series:

$$
f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n
$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

From Cauchy's Integral Formula we have:

$$
a_n=
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
$$

So,

$$
|a_n| \le |\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz| \le \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{n+1}}|dz| \le \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{1 + 2|z|^{10/3}}{|z|^{n+1}}|dz| 
$$

Therefore,

$$
|a_n| \le \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{1 + 2R^{10/3}}{R^n}dz
$$

And for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$
|a_n|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim\limits_{R\to+\infty}\frac{1+2R^{10/3}}{R^n}
$$
which implies $a_n=0$ for all $n \ge 4$. It follows that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of at most degree 3.

I'm having trouble coming up with a lower bound to show that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of at least degree 3.

Comment: Surely $f(z)$ doesn't need to have degree at least 3. If $f(z) \equiv 0$, then $f$ satisfies the inequality and is entire.

Comment: @matt here is a duplicate post with a tentative solution http://math.stackexchange.com/q/213491/43176

Comment: ah! sorry, I didn't see it because it was a new post. thanks!

Comment: You can save a lot of work by using Cauchy Estimates: $$|a_n| \le \frac{n!M(R)}{R^n} .$$ In this case for $n\ge 4$ the right hand side goes to zero for big $R$. Here $M(R)$ is the maximum value of the modulus of $f$ on a circle with center at 0 and radius $R$.

Comment: @PantelisDamianou Thanks for that hint! You're right, it makes the problem much easier.