# Holomorphic function bounded by $|z|^\frac{1}{2}$ or $|z|^\frac{3}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is that:
    On $C-\{0\}$ the function is holomorphic and satisfies $|f(z)|\le C|z|^{3/2}$ (or $|f(z)|\le C|z|^{1/2}$). $C$  here is the constant. Show that $f=0$？

Comment: For the case of $3/2$ take note that linear functions fill the bill.

Comment: Linear functions do not satisfy the inequality when $|z|<1$.

Comment: Please see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227226/entire-function-bounded-by-polynomial-of-degree-3-2-must-be-linear) for correct solutions to the case of $|z|^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take g=f/z^(3/2),
  then g has a analytic continuation or has pole. in the neighbourhood of 0, a meromorphic function takes all values in a nhbd. of inifinity.so it cannot be bounded by any constant.but |g| < C by assumption. in the same way other one.

Comment: Thank you! So you can show that g is a constant a, $f=az^{1/2}$, but why a must be zero?

Comment: i can show that g has a analytic continuation which implies f has a zero of order atleast 2 at zero.

Comment: yeah, and that will give us the solution for 3/2 case, great !

Comment: You can not conclude that $f(z)/z^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ a priori, because when $f$ is not  $0$, $f(z)/z^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is even not well defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. @SimingHE

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and satisfy the inequality $|f(z)| \leq C|z|^{1/2}$. First note that the singularity at $0$ is removable and indeed $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(z)=0$ from the inequality. So $f$ extends to an entire function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$. Note that $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is also an entire function. But we also have that

$$|f(z)/z| \leq \frac{C}{|z|^{1/2}},$$

in particular $g$ is bounded by $C$ outside the unit disk and since it is continuous it is bounded inside the unit disk. Thereby $G$ is a constant function and we must have that $g=0$.