# A property of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for all analytic functions $f : \Bbb{C}\longrightarrow\Bbb{C}$ such that for all $z$ satisfy  $|f(z)|^5 \leq |z|^6$. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the condition you get $f(0)=0$, hence either $f=0$ or $f(z)=z^k g(z)$ for some $k>0$ and $g$ entire with $g(0)\ne 0$.
Now $|g(z)|^5\le |z|^{6-5k}$ for all $z\ne 0$.
If $k>1$, this implies that $g$ is bounded, hence constant, but $f(z)=cz^k$ is no solution if $k>1$, $c\ne 0$.
Therefore $k=1$ and $|g(z)|^5\le|z|$ for $z\ne0$ and by continuity also for $z=0$, contradicting $g(0)\ne 0$.

Therefore $f(z)=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: How do you get the implication that "either $f=0$ or $f(z) = z^kg(z)$ for some $k >0$ ??

Comment: Analytic implies $f$ is the sum of a Taylor series at zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem hinges on the following result

> If $f(z)$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|\leq B|z|^n$, $B>0,\, n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$,  then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Nice Result. Would you give me a reference ?

Comment: @Drop: see [here](http://planetmath.org/liouvillestheorem).

Comment: @Drop: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227226/entire-function-bounded-by-polynomial-of-degree-3-2-must-be-linear).