# How to prove a harmonic function is a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, harmonic-functions

Given $u(x)$ be entire harmonic function on $\mathbb R^n$ , and
satisfy $u(x)\geq-C \left(1+|x|\right)^m$, where $C$ and $m$ are constants. ($m$ is an integer)
Prove $u(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $m$.

I tried Taylor series and tried to show the derivatives after $m$ vanish. but it seems unsuccessful.

Comment: Use the Poisson integral to show that the derivatives of higher order vanish.

Comment: Check the [result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453369/a-property-of-analytic-functions) I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting $u(0)$ from $u$, we may assume $u(0)=0$. Since the average of $u$ on every sphere $S_r=\{x:|x|=r\}$ is zero, it follows that the average of $|u|$ is controlled by the negative part $u^-=\max(0,-u)$: 
$$\frac{1}{|S_r|}\int_{S_r }|u| 
= \frac{1}{|S_r|}\int_{S_r }(u^+ +u^-)
=\frac{2}{|S_r|}\int_{S_r }  u^- \le 2C(1+r)^m \tag{1}$$

Harmonic functions satisfy the following  interior regularity estimate: 
For every multiindex $\alpha$, 
$$
|D^{(\alpha)}u(0)|\le \frac{C}{|S_r|\,r^{|\alpha|}} \int_{S_r }|u|
\tag{2} $$
This is probably somewhere in Chapter 2 in the book by Gilbarg-Trudinger, but is not hard to prove anyway. By rescaling, (2) reduces to the case $r=1$. Then write $u$ as the Poisson integral, differentiate the kernel accordingly, and use the inequality of the sort
$$
|D^{(\alpha)}u(0)|\le   
C\int_{S_1 }|u P^{(\alpha)} | 
\le  C\int_{S_1 }|u   | 
  $$
From (1) and (2), the desired conclusion $D^{(\alpha)}u(0)=0$ for $|\alpha|>m$ follows by letting $R\to \infty$.

Comment: How does subtracting u(0) from 0 ensure that u satisfies the bound?

Comment: @mononono Well, isn't it that we can adjust the constant $C$ and make this happen? We couldn't actually add any constant to $u$ and push it up or down?