# Prove that a complex function is linear

Tags: complex-analysis

I am dealing with this problem:

Let $f: \Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$ entire function such that for each $z\in\Bbb C$ :

$|f(z)| \leq A +B|z|^\frac{3}{2}$

Prove $f$ is linear.

I thought using Liouville's theorem, but it is about completely bounded function.I thought somehow to conclude that because the function is bounded by specific $z$ I can deduce the function is linear. I am struggling to formalize it properly.

Comment: This has been asked many times. Let $g(z)=\frac {f(z)-f(0)} z$ for $z \neq 0$ and $g(0)=f'(0)$. Check that $g$ is a bounded entire function.

Comment: And how does it show that $f$ is linear?

Comment: If $g$ is constant what is $f$? Can you write  $f$ in terms of $g$?

Comment: OK, I get that now. Thanks you!

Comment: Need to solve it without Taylor series

Comment: Here is another straight forward solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227226/42969